# Segfault on accessing elements of dynamic 2d array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, malloc

My goal is to create a function that converts a string into an array of "words" resulted from splitting an initial string by a delimiter. All words should be null-terminated. 
For example: strtoarr("**hello***world*", "*") should result in {"hello", "world"}. Here's my function.

```
char    **strtoarr(char const *s, char c)
{
    char    **arr;
    size_t  i;
    size_t  j;
    size_t  k;

    arr = malloc(sizeof(**arr) * (strlen(s) + 2));
    if (arr == 0)
        return (NULL);
    i = 0;
    k = 0;
    while (s[i] != '\0')
    {
        j = 0;
        while (s[i] != c)
        {
            arr[k][j] = s[i];
            if (s[i + 1] == c || s[i + 1] == '\0')
            {
                j++;
                arr[k][j] = '\0';
                k++;
            }
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        j = 0;
        while (s[i] == c)
            i++;
    }
    arr[k] = 0;
    return (arr);
}
```

It works only with empty strings and segfaults with everything else. I believe the problem is here.

```
arr[k][j] = s[i];
```

But I don't understand what the problem is.
Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no array in your code

Comment: @4386427 malloc in this code gives a chunk of memory which is incorrectly pointed at by a `char**` - a type which doesn't correspond with the size of the allocated chunk. It cannot be used as an array of pointers since it is incorrect.

Comment: @4386427 malloc does not give an array.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of problems with your code but the most important is the dynamic allocation. Your code does not allocate memory for saving an array of strings (aka an array of array of char).

This line:

```
arr = malloc(sizeof(**arr) * (strlen(s) + 2));
```

allocates memory for saving a number chars (i.e. `strlen(s) + 2` chars) but that is not what you want. Especially not when `arr` is a pointer to pointer to char.

A simple approach that you can use is to allocate an array of char pointers and then for each of these pointers allocate an array of char.

This would be:

```
char** arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * NUMBER_OF_WORDS_IN_INPUT);

arr[0] = malloc(NUMBER_OF_CHARACTERS_IN_WORD0 + 1);
arr[1] = malloc(NUMBER_OF_CHARACTERS_IN_WORD1 + 1);
...
arr[NUMBER_OF_WORDS_IN_INPUT - 1] = malloc(NUMBER_OF_CHARACTERS_IN_LAST_WORD + 1);
```

Then you can store characters into `arr` using the syntax

```
arr[i][j] = SOME_CHARACTER;
```

**without segfaults**. (It is of cause required that `i` and `j` is within bounds of the allocation).

Comment: "allocates memory for saving a number of pointers (i.e. strlen(s) + 2 pointers) but not any memory for saving characters". No. It allocates `sizeof(char) * (strlen(s) + 2)` bytes, which is nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

The inner while loop need to end if `s[i]` is `NULL` : `while (s[i] != c && s[i] != '\0')`

You check for `s[i + 1]` in your `if` statement but you continue looping.

Also you are allocating way more bytes than necessary, you could have a buffer of same size of your input string, and when the delimiter or NULL is found, you allocate a new row in your array of the needed size and copy the buffer into it.